# Cannot right click desktop windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu, right-click

This occurred after a Trojan incident. We managed to get the Trojan cleaned off the computer, but now we can't Right click the desktop.  We have tried changing *HKCU/software/microsoft/windows/current version/policies/explorer/noviewcontextmenu* in the registry, and *group policy user configuration/administrative templates/windows explorer/remove windows explorers default context menu*, but neither worked.

How do we reenable the right-click menu for the desktop? (it works everywhere else)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's not opening due to a corrupted or faulty menu entry...

You can enable/disable and remove Shell menu entries using [ShellMenuView from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html).

Perhaps it can lead you to a culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem....due to FakeAlert Trojan.  All files on c: were hidden, desktop image was removed, desktop Icons were removed, Start Menu items were gone...along with all the garbage alerts about hard disk problems.

I removed FakeAlert with MalwareBytes and SuperAntiSpyware, but at least in my case the system was still only half repaired, but at least the trojan was removed.

After some research, I had to run the "attrib *.* -h /s /d" command from c:\ to see all of the files again. I ran this from a "cmd" window (i.e. a DOS command line).  But at that point the desktop was still blank and I had no right-click context menu on the Desktop.  Also, since the START menu was blank, I had to lauch the "cmd" from the Task Manager, with "File - New Task (Run..)"

The Nirsoft tool mentioned above was neat, but didn't help with this.

I finally found a little script (for XP only) at http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm
...which re-enabled the desktop icons and right-click context menu on the Desktop.  The script is called "Enable/Disable Desktop Icons", and it worked like a charm.  When it is run, the script will toggle-on / toggle-off (depending on current state) the icons.  If it ys that they have been disabled when you first run it, just run it again, and it will enable them.

Once I had control of the Desktop again, I re-enabled my Desktop background...but this is in "Control Panel - Display - Properties" anyway.

Good Luck!!

Comment: As you can see by the date on this question, it's about 9 months old.  I've long since stopped working on the problem. In fact, I can't even remember what I did, probably just reformatted the machine.

Comment: Yes, I figured it was resolved by now, but wanted to post a fix that worked for others to use.  Too bad you had to reformat.  Too many times this is the case due to garbage malware issues.  Regards.